# Windows 7 not showing disks

Tags: hard-drive, hard-drive-failure

After a few minutes of turning on my pc, I go to access "computer" to show my disks and it just sits there refreshing. I go to "computer>manage" and then click "disk management" and again it just sits there doing nothing.

Is there something wrong with one of my disks? overheating perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it could be a problem with your hard drive. It could also be a bad CD/DVD drive if there's a CD/DVD inserted or it could be a bad CD/DVD if one is inserted. It could also be a faulty/flaky USB drive if one is attached.

Comment: I would Check in "Safe Mode" in this situation. please List your computer specs or at least all of the storage devices. "pull things" get down to less things plugged in any USB, and even pull net cable for a while to test.  Secure your data with a backup as soon as you see it. Provide more information about system and connections and use and all.